# Load csv and pass each value into a url parameter?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, web-scraping, parameter-passing

I'm trying to aggregate NBA player data from nba.com. I have a list of player ids in a csv. I want to load each player id and pass it into the parameters list. And then use the parameters list in a requests.get. The request.get works when I enter a player id directly as a parameter. And tests of the csv looping through the function appears to work. However, I am having trouble passing the playerids into the parameter list successfully. I've tried looking at similar nba python codes and can't see where I'm going wrong.

'''

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import csv

best_db=pd.DataFrame()


def table_Scrape():
    
    global best_db 
    
    with open("SHORT_ID_plyr.csv", "r") as f_urls: 
        f_urls_list = csv.reader(f_urls, delimiter=',') 
        next(f_urls_list)    
        
        ##step5. open 1st url from .csv
        for lines in f_urls_list:        
            u = lines[0]
            print(u) #<loop test
            # import requests
            player_id = u
            
            url = """
            http://stats.nba.com/stats/playergamelogs?DateFrom=&DateTo=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=Totals&Period=0&PlayerID=203932&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2021-22&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&VsConference=&VsDivision=
            """
                #url = """
                #https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashplayerstats?College=&Conference=&Country=&DateFrom=&DateTo=&Division=&DraftPick=&DraftYear=&GameScope=&GameSegment=&Height=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=Totals&Period=0&PlayerExperience=&PlayerPosition=&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2021-22&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&TwoWay=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&Weight=
                #"""
            header_dict = {
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
                'x-nba-stats-origin': 'stats',
                'x-nba-stats-token': 'true',
                'Referer': 'https://stats.nba.com',
                'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                'Pragma': 'no-cache',
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                'Host': 'stats.nba.com'
            }

            params = {
                'LastNGames': '0',
                'LeagueID': '00',
                'MeasureType': 'Base',
                'Month': '0',
                'OpponentTeamID': '0',
                'PORound': '0',
                'PaceAdjust': 'N',
                'PerMode': 'Totals',
                'Period': '0',
                'PlayerID': u,
                'PlusMinus': 'N',
                'Rank': 'N',
                'Season': '2021-22',
                'SeasonType': 'Regular+Season'
                }

            res = requests.get(url, headers=header_dict, params=params)
            json_set = res.json()
            headers = json_set['resultSets'][0]['headers']
            data_set = json_set['resultSets'][0]['rowSet']
            df = pd.DataFrame(columns=headers)
            df.head #test the dataframe NOTE: does not appear to be working either
            
table_Scrape() #call the function
```

Comment: supply a sample of `SHORT_ID_plyr.csv` file

Comment: PLAYER_ID
1629760
1629752
1629750
1629744
1629741
1629740
1629738
1629735

Comment: can you post the csv file somewhere so I can see how the file is being read in?

Comment: sure, my bad - how's this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DscQ-JM03jRP7i7ZNZP2I6QzyYzS7l0N/view?usp=sharing

Comment: ok just sent you a request for access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the payload onto a url that already has the payload with a hardcoded player id. Put the palyer_id variable into the url

```
import pandas as pd
import requests


best_db=pd.DataFrame()


def table_Scrape():
    
    df = pd.read_csv('SHORT_ID_plyr.csv')
    player_id_list = list(df['PLAYER_ID'])
        
    for player_id in player_id_list:
        print(player_id)
        url = f"""http://stats.nba.com/stats/playergamelogs?DateFrom=&DateTo=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&MeasureType=Base&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PaceAdjust=N&PerMode=Totals&Period=0&PlayerID={player_id}&PlusMinus=N&Rank=N&Season=2021-22&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&ShotClockRange=&VsConference=&VsDivision="""

        header_dict = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
            'x-nba-stats-origin': 'stats',
            'x-nba-stats-token': 'true',
            'Referer': 'https://stats.nba.com',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Pragma': 'no-cache',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Host': 'stats.nba.com'
        }

        res = requests.get(url, headers=header_dict)
        print(res.text)
        json_set = res.json()
        headers = json_set['resultSets'][0]['headers']
        data_set = json_set['resultSets'][0]['rowSet']
        df = pd.DataFrame(data_set,columns=headers)
        print(df.head()) #test the dataframe NOTE: does not appear to be working either
            
table_Scrape() #call the function
```

Comment: thanks! This is a very helpful explanation. I tried running the code however and am encourtering a new error. On ~line 42 at json_set = res.json(), I get a jsondecodeerror. I tried running your full code block and also making your changes to my code directly and still encounter the issue.

Comment: at what ID does it get tripped up at?

Comment: in other words, whats the last `print(u)` that is on the screen before the error?

Comment: I get stuck after the first player_id prints

Comment: ok. let me download your file and debug on my end

Comment: just tried the code above. Not sure what the issue is, as it works fine for me. I added one print statement in there, can you see what it returns?

Comment: I got it working in a different version of the file. I incorporated your comments into this other version and it worked as expected. I'm guessing the notebook I was working in has some other weird error in it. Thank you!!